# How can i insert data in an sqlite table from a text file in android

Tags: android

In my application I am creating many tables in the sqlite database but in that one table contains more than 100k rows I get data from server using http connection. Getting this kind of many records causing much more time for me so to avoid this problem I want to connect my tablet through PC and I want to place txt file(which has insert statements) in the tablet.

Now how can I access that txt file in my application and how can I insert data in my table using that txt file and into which location I have to copy this txt file to access it from my application.

My DB file size also 273 MB, so I don't think it's possible to place it in the assets folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can copy the file to `assets` folder

code example:

```
private void initDatabaseData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(file_name)), 1024 * 4);
        String line = null;
        db.beginTransaction();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            db.execSQL(line);
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "read database init file error");
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "buffer reader close error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

above code require **the every line of the txt file is a sql sentence**

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand how to use this and  How can i insert it in my table

Comment: and also my db file size is 273 MB